# TDD and Business Rules - Web API 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, tdd, inversion-of-control

Wondering if I'm doing this right?

**Business Rules**

1. `Customer` can **NOT** exist in system w/o `Property`.
2. When we delete a `Property` the `Customer` is deleted too.
3. The **ONLY** time I add a `Customer` is when I'm adding a `Property`. (see below)

***The POST: JSON Data from Client***

```
// http://localhost:3541/api/property

{
    City: "Demo City",
    Customer: {Id: 0, Name: "New Customer", Email: "customer@customer.com"},
    Id: 0,
    Name: "Custom Property Name",
    State: "LA",
    StreetAddress1: "123 Main St.",
    StreetAddress2: "Apt 1",
    Type: {Id: 15, Name: "Developer"},
    UserId: 174,
    Zip: "12345"
}
```

***The Controller***

```
[Route("api/property")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<int> AddProperty(Property property)
{
    return await propertyManager.AddProperty(property);
}
```

***Property Manager Class***

```
class PropertyManager{
    PropertyManager(){
        ...
    }
    PropertyManager(PropertyRepo propertyRepo){
        ...
    }

    public int AddProperty(Property property){

        int propId = await _propertyRepo.AddProperty(property);

        // associate with customer
        AddCustomer(property.Customer, propId); // here is my question (see below)
    }

     // again, here is my question (see below)
    private int AddCustomer(Customer customer, int propId){
        int custId = _propertyRepo.AddCustomer(customer, propId);
    }       
}
```

***Property Class***

```
class Property{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string StreetAddress1 {get; set;}
    ...

    public Customer Customer {get; set;}
}
```

In my Unit Test I am testing the Business Logic to of the `PropertyManager` class to see if I can Add a `Property` correctly.

**Consequently**, a `Customer` is created in the process.  This MUST be done at same time - during the same POST (as the JSON describes above).

Now, my question is:

(Or the way I am about to proceed is)

I am testing the Business Logic of my ability to add a `Property`.  The rules above state I will NEVER add a `Customer` w/o 1st adding a `Property`.  My unit test are therefore    `Property` centric.

I am asserting that it is okay to test the ability to Add a `Customer` through the `Property` and with my day.

Correct?!?

Or would you suggest re-architecting the system to decouple to Property and Customer when there is a STRONG REAL WORLD Coupling of these two Classes, the later cannot exist with the former.

Answer (score 1):

TDD is about testing the business rules so saying TDD vs Business rules is somewhat contradictory.

My guess is you are worried about testing more than one thing in your test but remember you can test more than one thing in a test if the are logically similar. So in your instance where the business rules is a customer must be created alongside the property having a test that tested this is completely fine.

For example you may have tests similar to these:

- GivenAPropertyWhenACustomerDoesNotExistThenExceptionThrown
- GivenAPropertyWhenPropertyValidAndCustomerValidThenPropertySuccessfullyAdded

Then your assertions would check across both property and customer

*Side comment*

You don't have to necessarily redesign your code but it does seem interesting a customer is created when a property is created so if one person had multiple properties they would be in your database multiple times? As I don't know your requirements or business this my be correct but does seem unique.

Also remember TDD is about writing the tests first, if you already written your code and are now writing tests this isnt TDD.

HTH